# Preserve source IP on wireguard VPN setup without using IP route

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn

I have the following setup

PC1 (wireguard client) -> PC2 (wireguard server, wg0, eth0) -> PC3 (tcp server)

192.168.1.100, 10.1.1.2->      192.168.1.101, 10.1.1.1      -> 192.168.1.102

192 subnet is the WIFI network.
10.1.1.0/24 is the wireguard network.

Question:

1. How can I setup using iptables only to let PC3 see the source IP of tcp packet is from 10.1.1.2?

using the following rules, it can reach the tcp server, but source IP is 192.168.1.101 (PC2, eth0)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.1.1.0/24 --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.102:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.0/24  -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.101
```

Update:

Question:

2. The reason we cannot use IP route is because when doing this in k8s, when use kube-proxy service in IP route, it throws next hop is invalid gateway.

Any way to archive this in k8s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Either you use `SNAT` (IP address is replaced), or you set up proper IP routing.

For specific application layer protocols like HTTP, you can use application level proxies.

Comment: we would like to do this in kubernetes, and IP route to set kube-proxy service IP as the gateway, it would say next hop is not a valid gateway. Any suggestion to preserve source IP in k8s?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I am not familiar with Kubernetes, so I cannot help here.

Comment: it works in k8s if use proxy protocol. nginx and vpn server both on same pod.

vpn server (redirect 80 to 8080 on nginx) -> nginx (proxy_protocol on) -> tcp server (headless service)